# Particles Rendered from Collection Are Missing Their Material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, particles, physics

I made a Blender File where I'm trying to emit "cold sparks" from a simple sphere. I created a sphere over a plane with a collision physics simulation on the plane. I put a particle system on the emitter sphere and set the render settings to "Collection" and selected "Embers" which contained my sparks objects. It looks like this:
[image]

I made the material for each ember a glowing yellow/organge that darkens with time.
[image]

But the embers that are emitted from the emitter sphere don't present with this glowing orange-ish material. They appear to not render AT ALL against the green plane (which is weird), and when visible, the embers present with the default white-ish material:

Can anyone show me how to get my particles to render with the correct material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot work, because lifetime and age are counted in frames.

But colorramp does take values only from 0 to 1.

So you should divide instead of add that values.

Also be aware that this node (particle info) only works in cycles.